# Browser based SSH

Tags: ssh, debian, lighttpd

I have a small debian server colocated which hosts a domain and a single flat file site via lighttpd. For a variety of reasons I'd like to be able to run ssh in browser (without a browser plugin) via HTTPS. I will need to create a self signed certificate, as I don't have the funds to pay for one.

I've seen various solutions such as [shellinabox](http://code.google.com/p/shellinabox/) and [gateone](https://github.com/liftoff/GateOne/).

Does anyone have experience or advice of which solution to use and how best to secure this?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various options like [NaCl](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_UJnWgQMVho), [fireSSH](http://firessh.net) and as you already mentioned [Shell In A Box.](http://code.google.com/p/shellinabox/) I'd personally recommend the last one if you need it for pentesting purposes, since it's the only one that actually uses SSL/TLS and would not trigger an alert in any IPS/Deep Packet Inspection device. (Most of these tools will trigger an alert since they are just browser based SSH or non SSL traffic through port 443)